# Chrome is eating my first inner <form> -- why?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit

Thanks to ASP.NET I get to learn the intracacies of getting away with <form> tags inside <form> tags.  I set up what I thought was a simple DOM that isn't working:

```
<form id="Superform" action="javascript: return false;">
<form id="Subform1" action="javascript: return false;">
    form1
</form>
<form id="Subform2" action="javascript: return false;">
    form2
</form>
</form>
```

In this example, IE8 seems to work normally, but Chrome (18.0.1025.142 beta-m) seems to make `Subform1` disappear.  Does anyone know why?  Is this a Chrome/webkit bug?  I made a jsFiddle to test it - if you have other browsers handy, I'm curious of those results too.

Try the example at http://jsfiddle.net/weQmk/9/.

In IE8 I get:

```
Forms my browser sees: 
Superform
Subform1
Subform2
```

But in Chrome:

```
Forms my browser sees:
Superform
Subform2
```

Comment: what's your doctype tag?  I believe that some doctypes do not support nested forms.  IE8 may just be more forgiving than chrome...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms

Comment: @Mike McMahon: Doctype is XHTML 1.0 Transitional.

Comment: http://anderwald.info/internet/nesting-form-tags-in-xhtml/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Forms cannot be nested in that way. On encounter of the closing `</form>` tag, the first open form is closed.

This is also illustrated in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/weQmk/11/

Comment: Okay (though this is quite irritating in ASP.NET-land, where your whole world is wrapped by a form) but it doesn't quite explain why Chrome makes one form disappear.. why doesn't it just close Superform and then write Subform?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433264/is-it-possible-to-wrap-html-form-elements-in-multiple-form-tags/9433497#9433497

Comment: I was wrong (original comment: "It seems to work nowadays (Chrome v42)."). It only seemed to work because I was wrapping my forms afterwards with another form. This at least works. And what also works: the form controls register themselves only to their parent form (i.e. it behaves as one would intuitively expect).