# Printing HTML with PHP function produces output which is wrongly interpreted by browser

Tags: php, html

maybe I am just too tired or missing something really fundamental, but I am growing frustrated.

I have table which contains data. I wrote php function which takes data from database and construct html table.

My problem is, that first row in table misses element in last table cell.

PHP function:

```
function printTable($stmt) {
    $result = '<table>';
    while ($data = $stmt -> fetch()) {
         $result .= '<tr>'
                     . '<td><span>' . $data['id'] . '</span></td>'
                     . '<td><span>' . $data['name'] . '</span></td>'
                     . '<td>'
                        . '<form method="post" action="">'
                           . '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $data['id'] . '">
                           . '<button type="submit" name="edit">Edit</button>'
                        . '</form>'
                     . '</td>'
                 . '</tr>';
    }
    $result .= '</table>';
    return $result;
}
```

The problem is that browser ignores form element in first row. Hidden input and button stay in place but without its parent form. So the output in browser looks like this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><span>1</span></td>
      <td><span>Foo</span></td>
      <td>
         <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
         <button type="submit" name="edit">Edit</button>
      </td>  
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><span>2</span></td>
      <td><span>Bar</span></td>
      <td>
         <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2">
            <button type="submit" name="edit">Edit</button>
         </form>
      </td>  
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><span>3</span></td>
      <td><span>Foo Bar</span></td>
      <td>
         <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="3">
            <button type="submit" name="edit">Edit</button>
         </form>
      </td>  
   </tr>
</table>
```

Furthermore, if I dump return value of this function, for example:  `var_dump(htmlspecialchars(printTable($stmt)));` it shows that first form is there, but in browser suddenly misses. Is it mysteriously dissapearing form magic?

Comment: Having a form element inside a td is not recommended, start the form before you start the table and finish it at the end of the table. you don't need the input tags either `<button type="submit" name="edit" value="3">`  should give you what you need. Plus I would question why you need a span inside your td. Also it looks like you are missing a few concatenations, rescan your code for missing `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just incase my suggestions were unclear I pulled your code out and faked your data

```
$allData = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Foo'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Bar'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Baz']
];
$result = '<form method="post" action=""><table>';
foreach ($allData as $data) {
    $result .= '<tr>'
        . '<td><span>' . $data['id'] . '</span></td>'
        . '<td><span>' . $data['name'] . '</span></td>'
        . '<td>'
            . '<button type="submit" name="edit" value="' . $data['id'] . '">Edit</button>'
        . '</td>'
    . '</tr>';
}
$result .= '</table></form>';
echo $result;
```

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to have one form for each row? I am going to make it editable row by row exclusively. Maybe I should wrap each `<tr>` with `<form>`? EDIT: I just read your previous comment, I can identify row with button value pair without using input tag.

Comment: I hope that then fixes your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems this behaviour is related to nested forms and how browsers handle them. Nested forms are invalid by specification.

See [Is it valid to have a hrml form inside another html form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555928/is-it-valid-to-have-a-html-form-inside-another-html-form) or [Chrome is eating my first inner form why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947529/chrome-is-eating-my-first-inner-form-why)

Comment: I would still recommend putting the form outside the table, see the solution I am posting.

Comment: Where exactly is there a form element inside another form element?

Comment: Not in question. But I used this function inside another form and when I started searching why browser removes that first nested form I learned about nested forms (sort of hardway) ...

Answer (score 1):

The output in the browser certainly doesn't look the way you've shown it, because your PHP code doen't output any indentation.

So what you're probably showing us is the browser's processed DOM, which may or may not represent the actual code that is being sent to the browser.

The chances are that the code the browser is receiving is invalid in some way or another, and what you're seeing is the browser's attempt to correct the mistakes.

Without seeing the rest of the page, I can't be certain what the invalid code actually looks like, but my guess is that you've got a `<form>` element already open prior to the table being output. You can't have nested `<form>`s, so the browser sees the first one inside the table and says to itself "oh, this is invalid". So it tries to fix it, and the result is that the inner form gets removed.

As I say, that's mostly speculation, and I can't be any more accurate without seeing the rest of the page, but I'd say it's likely a fairly close guess.

In any case, you can find out for yourself what the problem really is by running the code through the W3C's HTML validator. You can find it, and other code validation tools here: https://www.w3.org/developers/tools

The easiest way to use it is to open the page in your browser, and use the "view source" option to see the actual HTML code (ie *not* the DOM code shown in the dev tools), and then copy+paste that into the form in the validator.

It should tell you pretty quickly what the problems are with your code.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

According to HTML specs, you cannot have a form inside of a table cell, but you can have a table inside of a form. Catharsis' answer is correct, but I am baffled as to why your first opening and closing form tag have disappeared, there must be other parts of your code that are causing this to happen. Anyhow, I would take the form outside the table and for ease of readability replace all the concatenation code with HEREDOC code.

```
function printTable($stmt) {
    $result = '<form method="post">';
    $result .= '<table>';
    while ($data = $stmt -> fetch()) {
         $result .= <<<HTML
             <tr>
                <td>{$data['id']}</td>
                <td>{$data['name']}</td>
                <td><button type="submit" name="edit" value="{$data['id']}">Edit</button></td>

             </tr>
HTML;
    }
    $result .= '</table>';
    $result .= '</form>';
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I like the use of the HEREDOC, I always forget about that in PHP, rarely use it I guess.