# My PHP credit card form not recognizing certain inputs and errors

Tags: php, forms, credit-card

I was following a tutorial from John Conde on Authorize.net's credit card input form using PHP and error dectection.

It went perfect but I decided to add input boxes for entering the payment amount and and removed the unneeded shipping address requirements;

Now when the submitted form inputs are incorrect or empty, they no longer turn red nor does the "amount" box actually recognize whether it's empty or filled. The error box still pops up to bad credit card submissions.

Here's the page(minus the design to simplify trouble shooting);

http://teetimelawncare.com/payment-form.php

EDIT: removed the non-credit card related code and stuff like the state and year expiration dates to make it smaller. the PHP code at the very bottom is for the red error popup box that shows to the user when they incorrectly fill out the form.

I was at this part of the tutorial if anyone wants to compare:
http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Handling-Online-Payments-Part-5-Processing-Payment-and-Handling/ba-p/10768

Code:

```
<?php
    $errors = array();
    if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
    {
        $credit_card           = sanitize($_POST['credit_card']);
        $expiration_month      = (int) sanitize($_POST['expiration_month']);
        $expiration_year       = (int) sanitize($_POST['expiration_year']);
        $cvv                   = sanitize($_POST['cvv']);
        $cardholder_first_name = sanitize($_POST['cardholder_first_name']);
        $cardholder_last_name  = sanitize($_POST['cardholder_last_name']);
        $billing_address       = sanitize($_POST['billing_address']);
        $billing_address2      = sanitize($_POST['billing_address2']);
        $billing_city          = sanitize($_POST['billing_city']);
        $billing_state         = sanitize($_POST['billing_state']);
        $billing_zip           = sanitize($_POST['billing_zip']);
        $telephone             = sanitize($_POST['telephone']);
        $email                 = sanitize($_POST['email']);
        $account  = sanitize($_POST['account']);
        $amount   = sanitize($_POST['amount']);


        if (!validateCreditcard_number($credit_card))
        {
            $errors['credit_card'] = "Please enter a valid credit card number";
        }
        if (!validateCreditCardExpirationDate($expiration_month, $expiration_year))
        {
            $errors['expiration_month'] = "Please enter a valid exopiration date for your credit card";
        }
        if (!validateCVV($credit_card, $cvv))
        {
            $errors['cvv'] = "Please enter the security code (CVV number) for your credit card";
        }
        if (empty($cardholder_first_name))
        {
            $errors['cardholder_first_name'] = "Please provide the card holder's first name";
        }
        if (empty($cardholder_last_name))
        {
            $errors['cardholder_last_name'] = "Please provide the card holder's last name";
        }
        if (empty($billing_address))
        {
            $errors['billing_address'] = 'Please provide your billing address.';
        }
        if (empty($billing_city))
        {
            $errors['billing_city'] = 'Please provide the city of your billing address.';
        }
        if (empty($billing_state))
        {
            $errors['billing_state'] = 'Please provide the state for your billing address.';
        }
        if (!preg_match("/^\d{5}$/", $billing_zip))
        {
            $errors['billing_zip'] = 'Make sure your billing zip code is 5 digits.';
        }
        if (empty($telephone))
        {
            $errors['telephone'] = 'Please provide a telephone number where we can reach you if necessary.';
        }
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $errors['email'] = 'Please provide a valid email address';
        }
        if (empty($account))
        {
            $errors['account'] = 'Please provide the Your Customer ID Number from your billing statement.';
        }
        if (empty($amount))
        {
            $errors['amount'] = 'Please enter a payment amount.';
        }
        // If there are no errors let's process the payment
        if (count($errors) === 0)
        {
            // Format the expiration date
            $expiration_date = sprintf("%04d-%02d", $expiration_year, $expiration_month);

            // Include the SDK
            require_once('./config.php');

            // Process the transaction using the AIM API
            $transaction = new AuthorizeNetAIM;
            $transaction->setSandbox(AUTHORIZENET_SANDBOX);
            $transaction->setFields(
                array(
                'amount' => $amount,
                'card_num' => $credit_card,
                'exp_date' => $expiration_date,
                'first_name' => $cardholder_first_name,
                'last_name' => $cardholder_last_name,
                'address' => $billing_address,
                'city' => $billing_city,
                'state' => $billing_state,
                'zip' => $billing_zip,
                'email' => $email,
                'card_code' => $cvv,
                'Customer ID Number' => $account,

                )
            );
            $response = $transaction->authorizeAndCapture();
            if ($response->approved)
            {
                // Transaction approved. Collect pertinent transaction information for saving in the database.
                $transaction_id     = $response->transaction_id;
                $authorization_code = $response->authorization_code;
                $avs_response       = $response->avs_response;
                $cavv_response      = $response->cavv_response;

                // Put everything in a database for later review and order processing
                // How you do this depends on how your application is designed
                // and your business needs.

                // Once we're finished let's redirect the user to a receipt page
                header('Location: thank-you-page.php');
                exit;
            }
            else if ($response->declined)
            {
                // Transaction declined. Set our error message.
                $errors['declined'] = 'Your credit card was declined by your bank. Please try another form of payment.';
            }
            else
            {
                // And error has occurred. Set our error message.
                $errors['error'] = 'We encountered an error while processing your payment. Your credit card was not charged. Please try again or contact customer service to place your order.';

    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Payment Form</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
        <style type="text/css">
            #errormessage
            {
                background-color: #FFE7E7;
                border: 3px solid #CC0033;
                color: #000000;
                margin: 20px ;
                padding: 10px;
                width: 420px;
                -moz-border-radius: 6px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
                border-radius: 6px;
                -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
                box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#FFEAEA), to(#FFB3B3));
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFEAEA, #FFB3B3);
                background: linear-gradient(#FFEAEA, #FFB3B3);
                float: left;
            }
            .labelerror
            {
                color: #ff0000;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            h3 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    line-height: 10px;
    padding-left: 17px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;;

}
            #credit
            {
            Position: relative;
            margin-left: 14px;
            height:620px;
            width:400px;
             -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
                border-radius: 6px;
                -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
                box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
                float: left;
            }
            #amount1
            {
            margin: 5px;
            height:620px;
            position: relative;
            width:400px;
             -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
                border-radius: 6px;
                -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
                box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc; 
                float: left;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

 <div id="amount1">  <h3> Payment Amount</h3><p>
               <form id="myform"> <label for="amount"<?php if (in_array('amount', $errors)) echo ' class="labelerror"'; ?>> $</label>
                <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" maxlength="5" value=""></form>
            </p>  <br><div id="phpdisplay"> <form action="payment-form.php" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" target="_self" id="search">
     <strong>Get your current balance by searching<br> your Customer ID number</strong><br>(Don't Know? Ask us on live chat or check your billing invoice):<br> <input type="text" name="term" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Search" />
    </form>


</form></div>
<div id="credit">
<h3> Credit Card Information</h3>
        <form id="myform" action="/payment-form.php" method="post">


 <p>
                <label for="credit_card"<?php if (in_array('credit_card', $errors)) echo ' class="labelerror"'; ?>>Credit Card Number</label>
                <input type="text" name="credit_card" id="credit_card" autocomplete="off" maxlength="19" value="">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="expiration_month"<?php if (in_array('expiration_month', $errors)) echo ' class="labelerror"'; ?>>Expiration Date</label>
                <select name="expiration_month" id="expiration_month">


                    <option value="12">12</option>
                </select>
                <select name="expiration_year" id="expiration_year">
                    <option value="0"> </option>

                    <option value="2019">2019</option>
                    <option value="2020">2020</option>
                    <option value="2021">2021</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="cvv"<?php if (in_array('cvv', $errors)) echo ' class="labelerror"'; ?>>Security Code</label>
                <input type="text" name="cvv" id="cvv" autocomplete="off" value="" maxlength="4">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="cardholder_first_name"<?php if (in_array('cardholder_first_name', $errors)) echo ' class="labelerror"'; ?>>Cardholder's First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="cardholder_first_name" id="cardholder_first_name" maxlength="30" value="">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="cardholder_last_name"<?php if (in_array('cardholder_last_name', $errors)) echo ' class="labelerror"'; ?>>Cardholder's Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="cardholder_last_name" id="cardholder_last_name" maxlength="30" value="">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="billing_address"<?php if (in_array('billing_address', $errors)) echo ' class="labelerror"'; ?>>Billing Address</label>
                <input type="text" name="billing_address" id="billing_address" maxlength="45" value="">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="billing_address2"<?php if (in_array('billing_address2', $errors)) echo ' class="labelerror"'; ?>>Suite/Apt #</label>
                <input type="text" name="billing_address2" id="billing_address2" maxlength="45" value="">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="billing_city"<?php if (in_array('billing_city', $errors)) echo ' class="labelerror"'; ?>>City</label>
                <input type="text" name="billing_city" id="billing_city" maxlength="25" value="">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="billing_state"<?php if (in_array('billing_state', $errors)) echo ' class="labelerror"'; ?>>State</label>
                <select id="billing_state" name="billing_state">
                    <option value="0"> </option>
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>


                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="billing_zip"<?php if (in_array('billing_zip', $errors)) echo ' class="labelerror"'; ?>>Zip Code</label>
                <input type="text" name="billing_zip" id="billing_zip" maxlength="5" value="">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="telephone"<?php if (in_array('telephone', $errors)) echo ' class="labelerror"'; ?>>Telephone Number</label>
                <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" maxlength="20" value="">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="email"<?php if (in_array('email', $errors)) echo ' class="labelerror"'; ?>>Email Address</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" maxlength="20" value="">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="account"<?php if (in_array('account', $errors)) echo ' class="labelerror"'; ?>>Customer ID number</label>
                <input type="text" name="account" id="account" maxlength="6" value="">
            </p>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Checkout">
            </p>
        </form></div><?php
    if (count($errors))
    {
?>
        <div id="errormessage">
            <h2>
                There was an error with your submission. Please make the necessary corrections and try again.
            </h2>
            <ul>
<?php
            foreach ($errors as $error)
            {
?>
                <li><?php echo $error; ?></li>
<?php
            }
?>
            </ul>
        </div>
<?php
    }
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Lastly, I wanted to move the checkout button outside the div form so I made the button like this(in the designed page, not the example above)

```
</form> <br>
    <form id="myform"><p class="center">
                <button form="myform" input type="submit" value="Checkout">
            </p></form>
```

The button works but it's not displaying the value as the label on my (WIP) designed page.

Comment: Please include only the minimal code necessary.. sorting through what you provided is difficult.

Comment: that's a LOT of code you expect us to debug for you.

Comment: edited the unecessary out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
<button form="myform" input type="submit" value="Checkout">
```

is not how the `<button>` element is constructed. It looks like you attempted to change an `<input />`. This is likely what you're after:

```
<button form="myform" type="submit">Checkout</button>
```

It also looks like you're duplicating the `id` on two different forms, which is invalid. Remove the `id` on the form that wraps the submit button, or change it to something else.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually several questions it seems to me.  Since there's several, I might get something mixed up, someone point out if I get something blaringly wrong.

RE: ""amount" box actually recognize whether it's empty or filled." --

You can't split the amount off into it's own form and have it go along with the rest of the elements in the other form element.  Everything you want to post has to be in the same form element. (Unless you use the html5 form attribute, but I don't think IE supports this yet. Someone correct me if I'm wrong please.  Even then, you wouldn't be adding more form elements if I recall correctly.)  See: [Is it possible to wrap html form elements in multiple form tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433264/is-it-possible-to-wrap-html-form-elements-in-multiple-form-tags) See the comments in the accepted answer for more details.

Regarding the boxes not changing with errors. --

```
<label for="billing_address2"<?php if (in_array('billing_address2', $errors)) echo ' class="labelerror"'; ?>>Suite/Apt #</label>
```

Should probably be:

```
<label for="billing_address2"<?php if (in_array('billing_address2', array_keys($errors))) echo ' class="labelerror"'; ?>>Suite/Apt #</label>
```

Your array is keyed with the element names, so your in_array should search the keys of the errors array.  (Note that this will change the labels colors, not the input boxes themselves. Put the class-setting code on the boxes if you want the boxes themselves to change.)

Button is addressed in another answer:

```
<button form="myform" type="submit">Checkout</button>
```

HTML5 outside of form element. Again, not sure if IE supports this. No need to wrap it in a form element btw, assuming you're targeting browsers that support the form attribute.

```
<button type="submit">Checkout</button>
```

Inside form.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out later tonight....I had success using the button but I haven't tried in IE, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Worked perfect! I made it function like I wanted!